# Why doesn't this "binding" code work as expected in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I am new to JavaFX. I am not able to understand why the code below doesn't work.

```
import javafx.util.Sequences;

def nums = [1..10];
var curr = 0;

var evenOrOdd = bind if (nums[curr] mod 2 == 0) "{nums[curr]} is an even number" else "{nums[curr]} is an odd number";

for (curr in [0..(sizeof nums -1)])
{
    println("{evenOrOdd}");
}
```

I am getting

```
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
1 is an odd number
```

If I change the code to

```
import javafx.util.Sequences;

def nums = [1..10];
var curr = 0;

var evenOrOdd = bind if (nums[curr] mod 2 == 0) "{nums[curr]} is an even number" else "{nums[curr]} is an odd number";

for (i in [0..(sizeof nums -1)])
{
    curr = i;
    println("{evenOrOdd}");
}
```

I get the correct output:

```
1 is an odd number
2 is an even number
3 is an odd number
4 is an even number
5 is an odd number
6 is an even number
7 is an odd number
8 is an even number
9 is an odd number
10 is an even number
```

Clearly, the counter increment in the loop is not treated as a value change and the bound expression is not re evaluated.

Can anyone please explain the concept behind this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *for* expression implicitly defines its iteration variable (that's why you didn't need to declare *i* in your second example). Even if there is already a variable with the same name, *for* will still create a new one for its scope. Your *bind* expression is bound to the *curr* variable outside of your *for* loop, not to the one inside your *for* loop. And the one outside of your loop doesn't change, so the bound expression will not change.

Example to demonstrate this behaviour of *for*:

```
var curr = 0;
var ousideCurrRef = bind curr;
println("Before 'for' loop: curr={curr}");
for (curr in [0..3])
{
    println("In 'for' loop: curr={curr} ousideCurrRef={ousideCurrRef}");
}
println("After 'for' loop: curr={curr}");
```

This will print:

```
Before 'for' loop: curr=0
In 'for' loop: curr=0 ousideCurrRef=0
In 'for' loop: curr=1 ousideCurrRef=0
In 'for' loop: curr=2 ousideCurrRef=0
In 'for' loop: curr=3 ousideCurrRef=0
After 'for' loop: curr=0
```

Thus the *curr* outside the *for* loop won't change if you modify a variable of the same name inside the *for* loop.