# JavaFX Bind/Loop question

Tags: java, javafx

Ok, I'm taking the JavaFX with Passion course and have an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

It's similar to this question -

[Why doesn't this "binding" code work as expected in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657486/why-doesnt-this-binding-code-work-as-expected-in-javafx)

```
def numbers = [1..10];
var currentNumber = 0;    

for (currentNumber in numbers){
var evenOrOdd = bind if (numbers[currentNumber] mod 2 == 0)
    "----{numbers[currentNumber]} is an even number"
    else "----{numbers[currentNumber]} is an odd number";
println("{evenOrOdd}");
}
```

and my output -

```
----2 is an even number
----3 is an odd number
----4 is an even number
----5 is an odd number
----6 is an even number
----7 is an odd number
----8 is an even number
----9 is an odd number
----10 is an even number
----0 is an even number
```

The issue I'm having is that it 'looks' to run right except it doesn't display 1 as an odd number and then it adds a 0 after the 10. I spent some time stepping through the program and can't seem to find out how/why it's doing this.

I can get it to run great without any binding so not sure if that's what's causing my problem.

Any ideas/thoughts?

~Allen

Comment: Why doesn't your code look like java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currentNumber is one of the elements of numbers, not the index

```
var evenOrOdd = bind if (currentNumber mod 2 == 0)
    "----{currentNumber} is an even number"
    else "----{currentNumber} is an odd number";
```

Comment: Yeah, figured that out this morning. Man, that's what happens when you try to code while tired. :D Thanks for the help!